# University Application and community service?

Tags: sharia, doubts, deeds, definitions, makruh

I am applying for universities this year; most of them ask for community service information when considering an applicant for a scholarship. I want to ask if I should give them that info. I did community service but without any intention to brag about it. Will it reduce the good deed or is it okay?

Comment: Why can't you submit to them the details normally without bragging and let not erase your good deeds ?